# Trouble accessing files on google drive from colab

Tags: json, file, google-colaboratory, flysystem-google-drive

I am having trouble accessing my google drive files from colab.

First I was successfully able to mount my google drive on colab

All of the following work :

**drive.mount(‘/content/gdrive’, force_remount=True)
%cd gdrive/MyDrive
%ls TriangulationSimulation\ SNOP
file1 = ‘TriangulationSimulation\ SNOP/nlog-dump-SNOP-json-950-0.json’
%cat $file1**

However I next try to open the very same file (file1) which is a json file :

**fsnop = open(file1)
(or fsnop = open(file1, “r”))**

and I get an error : **'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ‘TriangulationSimulation\ SNOP/nlog-dump-SNOP-json-950-0.json’**

No idea why this is happening - I tried to do it with the full path name and also relative to MyDrive/ - no avail - I am able to access as you can see the file no problem at first and then when I give the file name to open - it doesn't work

(My next step will be to load the json data by doing json.load(fsnop))

thanks for any help !
Farrukh